# In the transclude function of a directive link function, how is "futureParentElement" used?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion, angularjs-ng-transclude

In the [angular documentation for the compile service (starting at line 412)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js?source=cc) there is a description of the transclude function that is passed into the linking function of a directive.

The relevant part reads:

```
function([scope], cloneLinkingFn, futureParentElement)
```

In which (line 212):

> `futureParentElement`: defines the parent to which the `cloneLinkingFn` will add the cloned elements.
>
> - default: `$element.parent()` resp. `$element` for `transclude:'element'` resp. `transclude:true`.
> - only needed for transcludes that are allowed to contain non html elements (e.g. SVG elements)
>     and when the `cloneLinkinFn` is passed,
>     as those elements need to created and cloned in a special way when they are defined outside their usual containers (e.g. like `<svg>`).
> - See also the `directive.templateNamespace` property.

I fail to see the point of `futureParentElement` however. It says

> defines the parent to which the cloneLinkingFn will add the cloned elements.

But you do that in the `cloneLinkingFn` itself like this:

```
transclude(scope, function (clone) {
    some_element.append(clone);
});
```

And you can't use the transclude function without defining the cloning function in the first place.

What is the proper usage/a use for `futureParentElement`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to this can be found by looking at the the [git blame of `compile.js`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blame/master/src/ng/compile.js): the commit that added `futureParentElement` is https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/ffbd276d6def6ff35bfdb30553346e985f4a0de6

In the commit there is a test that tests a directive `svgCustomTranscludeContainer`

```
directive('svgCustomTranscludeContainer', function() {
  return {
    template: '<svg width="400" height="400"></svg>',
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrls, $transclude) {
      var futureParent = element.children().eq(0);
      $transclude(function(clone) {
        futureParent.append(clone);
      }, futureParent);
    }
  };
});
```

by testing how compiling the html `<svg-custom-transclude-container><circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1"></circle>` behaves:

```
it('should handle directives with templates that manually add the transclude further down', inject(function() {
  element = jqLite('<div><svg-custom-transclude-container>' +
      '<circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1"></circle></svg-custom-transclude-container>' +
      '</div>');
  $compile(element.contents())($rootScope);
  document.body.appendChild(element[0]);

  var circle = element.find('circle');
  assertIsValidSvgCircle(circle[0]);
}));
```

So it looks like if you are creating an SVG image with a directive whose template wraps transcluded SVG content in `<svg> ... </svg>` tags, then that SVG image won't be valid (by some definition), if you don't pass the correct `futureParentElement` to `$transclude`.

Trying to see what it actually means not to be valid, beyond the test in the source code, I created 2 directives based on the ones in the unit test, and used them to try to create an SVG image with partial circle. One using the `futureParentElement`:

```
<div><svg-custom-transclude-container-with-future><circle cx="1" cy="2" r="20"></circle></svg-custom-transclude-container></div>
```

and one that is identical but that doesn't:

```
<div><svg-custom-transclude-container-without-future><circle cx="2" cy="2" r="20"></circle></svg-custom-transclude-container></div>
```

As can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/meRZylSgNWXhBVqP1Pa7?p=preview, the one with the `futureParentElement` shows the partial circle, and the one without doesn't. The structure of the DOM appears identical. However Chrome seems to report that the second `circle` element isn't an SVG node, but a plain HTML node.

So whatever `futureParentElement` actually does under the hood, it seems to make sure that transcluded SVG content ends up being handled as SVG by the browser.

Comment: So it is irrelevant to html content, isn't it?

Comment: @krave I believe so: "only needed for transcludes that are allowed to contain non html elements"